# SQL Server : How to use a column value in same select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which is fetching values from multiple tables, it looks some thing close to the below query.

I have highlighted in bold the place where i need to pass the value returned from the same query.

```
 select E.[EmployeeName] as EmployeeName
, (select City from tblEmployeeCities where C.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID) as EmployeeCity
, (Select State from tblStates **where City =  /i need to give the name of 
the city returned by the above statement**  ) as EmployeeState
from tblEmployees E
```

Comment: You should check: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JOIN/LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeName, C.City, S.State
FROM tblEmployees E
LEFT JOIN tblEmployeeCities C ON C.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN tblStates S ON S.City=C.City
```

Comment: Except you need to replace the `WHERE` in the first `JOIN` with `ON`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
select E.[EmployeeName] as EmployeeName
    , c.City as EmployeeCity
    , (Select State from tblStates where City = c.City ) as EmployeeState
from tblEmployees E
    inner join tblEmployeeCities C on C.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved with a CASE WHEN ELSE END statment in the select part of your sql statment.

Look at example here for syntax or usage: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp